# Creating a new column from another column + unique numeric index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe in which several rows of a column have the same value:

```
   unique_code      0
0   p01_PAR_1  zertara
1   p01_PAR_1    atera
2   p01_PAR_1       da
3   p01_MOT_1       ez
4   p01_MOT_1    dakit
```

I would like to redo that column or create a new one with one unique value, by **adding a numeric index after the value**, so it would result on something like this:

```
   unique_code       0
0   p01_PAR_1_1  zertara
1   p01_PAR_1_2    atera
2   p01_PAR_1_3       da
3   p01_MOT_1_1       ez
4   p01_MOT_1_2    dakit
```

This **cannot be done by adding the row index** to each row, since they have different and unrelated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GroupBy.cumcount` then add it as a string:

```
df['unique_code'] = (
    df['unique_code'] + 
    '_' + 
    df.groupby('unique_code').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
)

   unique_code        0
0  p01_PAR_1_1  zertara
1  p01_PAR_1_2    atera
2  p01_PAR_1_3       da
3  p01_MOT_1_1       ez
4  p01_MOT_1_2    dakit
```